# Installing PHP CLI Extensions in Windows

Tags: php, windows, curl, command-line-interface, mcrypt

I have PHP5 installed under Windows and IIs but now I find I need to install some additional extensions, but I have been having difficulty finding the specifi dll files for the extensions I need to install.

Specifically trying to install:

- PHP CLI Extension
- PHP MCrypt Extension
- PHP Curl Extension
- Curl

PHP documentation sates the dlls need to go into the C:\PHP\ext directory but I can not find the DLLs anywhere on the internet in order to install them.

Found similar question with other extension here [Installing PHP extensions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250766/installing-php-extensions-on-windows/32085655?noredirect=1#comment52068036_32085655)
But can not find any specifics for the extensions I need.

Comment: verify installations by using phpinfo();                                                                For installing CLI check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line  , For installing other extensions use this http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP Installation of extensions on Windows
[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php)

1. PHP CLI Extension Installation [Command Line PHP on Microsoft Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php)
2. PHP MCrypt Extension [PHP Mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)
3. PHP Curl Extension [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)