# Installing one PHP extension for a program on Windows

Tags: php, windows, php-extension

sorry if I seem like an absolute beginner at these things. I wanted to get the [PHP extension for GEOS](https://git.osgeo.org/gitea/geos/php-geos). I already have PHP (though XAMPP) and GEOS installed. Now, trying out the instructions on GitHub, I soon realize that these are instructions for Linux. I've been googling instructions for getting PHP extensions in Windows, but [I've learned that it's not quite simple.](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php) Based on what I've found I would either need to

- Use Visual Studio (which I would have to download first)
- Find a dll (there is none)
- Recompile PHP with the extension (not sure if I said it right)

So I have two questions: firstly, which of these options are most suitable for getting just one extension? And secondly, regarding the recompiling option, would I have compile things from a different source, since I got PHP from XAMPP and it doesn't seem to have the option to install the components separately.

EDIT: I believe that my question is not the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250766/installing-php-extensions-on-windows) because the user here actually found relevant DLLs, and did not have to compile anything or use Visual Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PHP extensions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250766/installing-php-extensions-on-windows)

Comment: @Phiter Hi, thanks but I don't think the answers on that one answer my question, because they were able to find DLLs, and didn't have to resort to using Visual Studio, compiling, or any other possible solution.