# Recompiling PHP, when I've previously installed it with XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, xampp, php-extension

I'm on Windows 10, and I really need to install this [PHP extension](https://github.com/libgeos/php-geos) in order to use advanced GeoPHP methods. [I've already asked about this previously here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822782/installing-one-php-extension-for-a-program-on-windows) There is no available DLL for this extension, and the instructions for installation on GitHub are for Linux. What I've understood is that I need to recompile PHP with the extensions in the ext folder, so I'm planning on doing that [using these instructions](https://www.sitepoint.com/compiling-php-from-source-on-windows/). However, I've previously installed PHP through XAMPP.

My question is, will these instructions work with this? If yes, where can I find the PHP source files? I'm not quite sure what they look like, and googling "PHP source files location" gives me stuff about actual PHP files, not the ones used for installation. I just want to make sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to recompile PHP. The module you stated is not baked into PHP but dynamically included.

Just build the module and include it like

```
extension=geos.dll
```

The Github link you posted does have instructions...

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what you mean. I tried the instructions (under "Procedure", right?) but they don't work on my Windows machine. I'm really just a beginner in PHP and all this, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the terms.

Comment: The steps for windows are similiar, Google for `how to compile a php extension on windows`.